# Win10 won't detect HP Laserjet by IP addr

Tags: windows-10, installation, printer, network-printer, laser-printer

I have an HP LaserJet 400 series printer installed on 192.168.1.25.  Wired PCs on the subnet can print to this printer just fine.  However, my wireless subnet is 192.168.20.0/24; Win10 PCs on 192.168.20.0/24 can ping the printer, but Windows 10 will not detect it.

I'm adding the printer in Windows 10 like this:

- Printers & scanners > Add a printer or scanner button
- Wait for Windows to search, then I click "The printer I want isn't listed"
- Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname > Next
- Device type: *Autodetect*, Hostname or IP address: *192.168.1.25* (I leave "Query the printer and automatically select the driver" checked) > Next
- Windows says it is contacting the printer, then it says "Detecting TCP/IP port"
- At this point, the detection process times out, saying "The device is not found on the network"

The problem is, I can open [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) on the computer which won't autodetect the printer and telnet to TCP 9100 (192.168.1.25).  I can also open the printer's web GUI from the wireless network with no problems...

There is no firewall in the way.  This isn't a firewall or network problem, AFAICT.

Question: *How do I force Windows10 to install this printer so I can print to it?*

Comment: Have you tried not automatically detecting the printer? What’s wrong with specifying the information manually? Have you confirmed this behavior on any other computer on this wireless subnet?

Comment: Instead of autodetect printer type, I also used "TCP/IP device".  I get the same result no matter what option I try.